# How to go backwards in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I need to write a simple function for one of my assignments that should remove all the duplicates from a given list except for the first occurrence of the element in the list.
Here is what I wrote:

```
remDup :: [Int]->[Int]
remDup []=[]
remDup (x:xs)
   | present x xs==True = remDup xs
   | otherwise = x:remDup xs
   where
   present :: Int->[Int]->Bool
   present x [] = False
   present x (y:ys)
       | x==y =True
       | otherwise = present x ys
```

But this code removes the duplicates except for the last occurrence of the element.
That is, if the given list is `[1,2,3,3,2]`, it produces `[1,3,2]` instead of `[1,2,3]`.
How to do it the other way around?

Comment: side note: `present x xs == True` is equivalent to `present x xs`

Comment: Why `reverse . nub . reverse` ? `nub` does exactly what Abhinav Jain is trying to write.

Comment: Cannot use built in functions as per the instructions of assignment that is why trying to implement it through simple functions and recursion.

Comment: @recursion.ninja But he *wants* `[1,2,3]` -- in other words, he wants `nub`. I agree that `reverse . nub . reverse` matches the function he has written, but he explicitly doesn't like the behavior of the function he has written.

Comment: @DanielWagner oh I misread his question, I thought the problem wasn't just straightforward recursion...

Comment: @recursion.ninja Yes what i actually want to do is exactly the same what `nub `does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this idea:

```
remDup [] = []
remDup (x:xs) = x :  remDup ( remove x xs )
```

where `remove x xs` removes all occurrences of x from the list xs (implementation left as an exercise.)

Comment: I've checked Data.List.nub and surprisingly it's O(n^2) too. Here's an interesting article: [nub considered harmful](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/02/nub-considered-harmful.html).

Answer (score 2):

For every element you encounter, you simply want to check if you have encountered it before; build up a Set of encountered elements and use that to check if an element should be deleted.

```
remDup :: [Int] -> [Int]
remDup xs = helper S.empty xs
  where
    helper s [] = []
    helper s (x:xs) | S.elem x s = helper xs
                    | otherwise = x:helper (S.insert x s) xs
```

Comment: Also, in case of Int a specialized highly efficient [IntSet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-IntSet.html) could be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse it, run your current duplicate remover, and then reverse the result.

Comment: That would work i know but still there must be a more efficient way to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I finally came up with after following user5402's advice.

```
remDup1 [] = []
remDup1 (x:xs) = x:remDup1(remove x xs)

remove x []=[]
remove x (y:ys) 
   | x==y = remove x ys
   | x/=y = y:(remove x ys)
```

Comment: Your last guard should always be trivial, to make it clear that you haven't missed any cases. This is usually done with `otherwise`, which is just defined as `True`.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about efficiency, you should think about using `HashSet` as an auxiliary data structure. Doing that, we can get an average-case complexity of O(n log n) and actually O(n) in practice ([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.10.0/docs/Data-HashSet.html)).

```
import Data.Hashable
import Data.HashSet (HashSet)
import qualified Data.HashSet as HashSet

remDupSet :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
remDupSet l = remDupSetAux HashSet.empty l
  where remDupSetAux :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => HashSet a -> [a] -> [a]
        remDupSetAux _ [] = []
        remDupSetAux s (x:xs) = if x `HashSet.member` s
                                  then remDupSetAux s xs
                                  else x : remDupSetAux (HashSet.insert x s) xs
```

I just quickly wrote a program to compare the performance of this solution with the top-voted one:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Hashable
import Data.HashSet (HashSet)
import qualified Data.HashSet as HashSet

import Data.Time.Clock
import Control.DeepSeq

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let a = [1..20000] :: [Int]
  putStrLn "Test1: 20000 different values"
  test "remDup"    $ remDup a
  test "remDupSet" $ remDupSet a
  putStrLn ""
  let b = replicate 20000 1 :: [Int]
  putStrLn "Test2: one value repeted 20000 times"
  test "remDup"    $ remDup b
  test "remDupSet" $ remDupSet b

test :: (NFData a) => String -> a -> IO ()
test s a = do time1 <- getCurrentTime
              time2 <- a `deepseq` getCurrentTime
              putStrLn $ s ++ ": " ++ show (diffUTCTime time2 time1)

remDup :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
remDup [] = []
remDup (x:xs) = x : remDup (delete x xs)

remDupSet :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
remDupSet l = remDupSetAux HashSet.empty l
  where remDupSetAux :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => HashSet a -> [a] -> [a]
        remDupSetAux _ [] = []
        remDupSetAux s (x:xs) = if x `HashSet.member` s
                                  then remDupSetAux s xs
                                  else x : remDupSetAux (HashSet.insert x s) xs
```

As expected, there is a huge difference mainly when there are many distinct values:

```
Test1: 20000 different values
remDup: 15.79859s
remDupSet: 0.007725s

Test2: one value repeted 20000 times
remDup: 0.001084s
remDupSet: 0.00064s
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Hashable` is evil and wrong. Notably, it is very stupid about hashing `Int` (very, very, very stupid), but it also makes hashes of different sizes on different architectures.

Comment: Why do you say that? What I see in the source code is `instance Hashable Int where hash = id`, which is no different from Java for example. Do you have any reference worth of reading about why "`Hashable` is evil and wrong"?

Comment: The problem is that hash tables, hash maps, and hash sets depend for their efficiency on keys being distributed as evenly as possible. Using the identity function for "hashing" does a pretty bad job of this.

Comment: Well, it's true you depend on the key distribution caused by the hashing function, but they are usually faster than their tree counterparts. Even, in this example, I started by using `Set` which is implemented with a tree, but than I changed, because `HashSet` was faster. And also because it looks better to say O(n) than O(n log n) :-)

Comment: You can't really get O(1) ever. Hash maps are based on trees. I believe the branching factor is large, so the trees are typically shallow.

Comment: Why `Ord` and not `Eq` for the `HashSet` version? Pretty sure you only need `Hashable` and `Eq`.

Comment: @dfeuer You're right. I must have mixed it with the `HashSet` from the `hashmap` package.